# Butterfly Raises Abdomen Like A Scorpion

Tags: entomology

Since a few weeks I am observing a little butterfly in my living room and normally I put insects out but it's cold outdoors and I thought it's secure inside. It occassionally flies around, especially since last 2 days and now I saw it is behaving differently. It has raised it's abdomen rectangularly (90 degrees) and it looked greenish with white stripes. When I tried to make a picture with flash on, it lowered it's tail and the color has also changed to a brown. The picture shown is just a couple minutes later taken without flash. I'm worrying if it's afflicted by a worm and I am thinking about if it's better to put it to rest in that case!?
As I am writing this line, it has lowered its tail further.

[image: Butterfly]